# Breaking determinant of a matrix on the basis of its column

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a square matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ of the form $A=[a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n]$. Let $a_i \in A$ be expressed as $a_i=\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j v_j$ where $v_j \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let us consider the matrices $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_m$ where $A_j$ matrix has same columns as that of $A$ except for the $i^{th}$ column, where $a_i$ is being replaced by $v_j$. Can we say something like this: $$\text{det}(A)=\sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j\text{det}(A_j)$$
If $a_i$ is expressed as elementwise multiplication of vectors $v_j$ then do we have any relationship like
$$\text{det}(A)=\Pi_{j=1}^m \text{det}(A_j)$$

Comment: This is simply saying that the determinant is linear as a function of the $i$-th column. Yes, this is true, and fairly well-known.

Comment: Thanks. So stupid of me. However if we replace summation by multiplication will it work?  i.e. if $a_i=\Pi_{j=1}^m v_j$ then can we say: $\text{det}(A)=\Pi_{j=1}^m\text{det}(A_j)$.

Comment: What would a product of vectors even be? (But anyway, the answer is "no"; there are no simple formulas like that.)

Comment: Thanks. By product I meant to write each element of $a_i$ is actually a product of its corresponding element in $v_j$. Something like element wise multiplication. I will edit the actual question to include this

Comment: Nah, still no chance. The degrees wouldn't match.

Comment: Can you elaborate your point about degrees ? I meant that if $a_i=(a_{i1},a_{i2},\ldots,a_{in})$ then $a_{ik}=\Pi_{j=1}^m v_{jk}$.

Comment: Yeah. The left hand side will be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $n-1 + m$ in the entries, but the right hand side will be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $nm$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64006/discussion-between-user402940-and-darij-grinberg).